# Saber si una cadena contiene ciertos caracteres

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, string, caracteres

Necesito determinar en C# si un string contiene algunos de estos caracteres !"·$%&/()=¿¡?'_:;,|@#€*+.

Pense en usar string.Contains pero tendria que hacerlo caracter por caracter. Existe alguna funcion similar pero que pueda buscar varios caracteres a la vez ?

Gracias!

Comment: Podrías usar una expresión regular: `/\!|\"|\·|\$|\%|\&|\/|\(|\)|\=|\¿|\¡|\?|[\_]|[\:]|[\;]|\|\@|\#|\€|\*|\+/g`.

Comment: Puedes usar tambien [IndexOfAny](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.indexofany?view=net-5.0#System_String_IndexOfAny_System_Char___), pasandole un array de char con todos los caracteres a comprobar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso lo puedes lograr con una funcion regular <<Las expresiones regulares son otro mundo aparte del mundo de c#, yo te recomiendo que indagues un poco ya que son muy utiles>>.

Para trabajar con expresiones regulares debes usar la libreria "System.Text.RegularExpressions" disponible tanto en ".Net Core" como en ".Net Framework". En tu caso, como solo quieres saber si existe una coincidencia, el metodo estatico "IsMatch" de la clase "Regex" te servira.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Busca si hay algun caracter extrano en el texto
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Texto">El texto que se analizara</param>
    /// <returns>Si el texto contiene algun caracter extrano</returns>
    static private bool HayCoincidencia(string Texto)
    {
        string Patron = "[!\"·$%&/()=¿¡?'_:;,|@#€*+.]";
        return Regex.IsMatch(Texto, Patron);
    }
```

solo le pasas el string que quieres analizar para ver si contiene algun caracter antes mencionados y te devolvera un booleano dependiendo si encuentra o no una coincidencia.

Si desea agregar los caracteres que se buscaran en el texto en tiempo de ejecucion, usa este otro metodo.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Busca si hay algun caracter extrano en el texto
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Texto">El texto que se analizara</param>
    /// <param name="CaracteresInvalidos">Caracteres no permitidos</param>
    /// <returns>Si el texto contiene algun caracter no permitido</returns>
    static private bool HayCoincidencia(string Texto, string CaracteresInvalidos)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CaracteresInvalidos))
            return false;

        return Regex.IsMatch(Texto, $"[{CaracteresInvalidos}]");
    }
```

Este metodo funcionara igual que el anterior, solo que en el segundo parametro le debes pasar un string con todos los caracteres que quieres buscar (no deben estar separados por nada)

Answer (score 1):

Bien podrías hacerlo con una expresión regular pero yo te propongo otra forma:

```
string caracteres = "!\"·$%&/()=¿¡?'_:;,|@#€*+.";
string palabra = "palabra!123&";

bool hayCoincidencias = (caracteres.Intersect(palabra).Count() > 0);
```

Declaras la **variable caracteres** que va a tener todos los caracteres que te interesan, como también te interesa el caracter `"` (doble comilla) para que sea aceptado debes anteponerle el caracter `"\\"`.

Posteriormente tendrías la palabra que analizarías y entonces vendría esta línea de código.

```
bool hayCoincidencias = (caracteres.Intersect(palabra).Count() > 0);
```

Donde el **método Intersect** es un **operador de conjunto**, el cual halla los elementos que hay en común en dos colecciones, es decir hallamos todos los elementos que hay en común entre la **variable palabra** y la **variable caracteres** y posteriormente llamamos al **método Count**, el cual nos va a contar todos los elementos que hay en común entre las dos cadenas, y en la **variable booleana hayConcidencias** va a ser **true** si existe al menos un caracter en común y **false** si no hay ninguno en común.

Answer (score 0):

mira lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma
Este código utiliza la función Any de LINQ junto con Contains para verificar si al menos uno de los caracteres en el string de entrada está presente en el conjunto de caracteres que deseas buscar. Puedes ajustar el valor de input según tus necesidades.

```
 private bool Validar(string texto)
    {
        

        // Caracteres a buscar
        string caracteresBuscar = "¡\"·$%&/()=¿¡?'_:;,|@#€*+.";

        // Verificar si el string contiene alguno de los caracteres
        bool contieneCaracterEspecial =texto.Any(caracter => caracteresBuscar.Contains(caracter));

        // Imprimir el resultado
        if (contieneCaracterEspecial)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Contiene Caracteres");
            return true;
           
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Contiene Caracteres");
            return false;
        }
       
    }
```